# All options first

Tags: javascript, php, html

Good day. Please help me. I created a select:

```
    <select id="type" multiple>
        <option value="63">1963</option>
        <option value="64">1964</option>
        <option value="65">1965</option>
        <option value="66">1966</option>
        <option value="67">1967</option>
        <option value="68">1968</option>
        <option value="69">1969</option>
        <option value="70">1970</option>
        <option value="71">1971</option>
        <option value="72">1972</option>
        <option value="73">1973</option>
        <option value="74">1974</option>
        <option value="75">1975</option>
        <option value="76">1976</option>
        <option value="77">1977</option>
        <option value="78">1978</option>
        <option value="79">1979</option>
        <option value="80">1980</option>
        <option value="81">1981</option>
        <option value="82">1982</option>
        <option value="83">1983</option>
        <option value="84">1984</option>
        <option value="85">1985</option>
        <option value="86">1986</option>
        <option value="87">1987</option>
        <option value="89">1989</option>
        <option value="91">1991</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <select id="kind" disabled multiple>
        <option></option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <select id="category" onchange="showhideBlocks(this.value)" disabled multiple>
        <option></option>
    </select>
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php
$types = array(
    63 => array(
        1 => 'Неизвестный'
        ),
    64 => array(
        1 => 'Неизвестный'
        ),
    65 => array(
        1 => 'Неизвестный'
        ),
    66 => array(
        1 => 'Alpha Industries, Inc.',
        2 => 'John Ownbey Company, Inc.',
        3 => 'Southern Athletic, Inc.',
        4 => 'Rolane Sportswear, Inc.',
        5 => 'Hamilton Tailoring',
        6 => 'Hirsch Tyler Co.',
        7 => 'Freeland Shirt Co.',
        8 => 'Atlantic Highlands Mfg. Co.',
        9 => 'Marcie Dale Inc.',
        10 => 'AG Outerwear Corp.'
        ),
    67 => array(
        1 => 'SAF-T-BAK Inc.',
        2 => 'Addleman Mfg. Co.',
        3 => 'SGS Mfg. Co.',
        4 => 'Kent Sportswear Inc.',
        5 => 'Harrigan BL Inc.',
        6 => 'Edwards Ralph Sportswear Inc.',
        7 => 'Dale Fashions Inc.',
        8 => 'Simon & Mogilner',
        9 => 'Crescent Sportswear Inc.',
        10 => 'Neptune Raincoat Co. Inc.',
        11 => 'Days Tailord Clothing Inc.',
        12 => 'Robitsher Schneider Co.',
        13 => 'Cherry Tree Suedes',
        14 => 'Bilamco Inc.',
        15 => 'Chief Apparel Inc.',
        16 => 'Rolane Sportswear, Inc.',
        17 => 'Alpha Industries, Inc.',
        18 => 'Allen Overall Co., Inc.',
        19 => 'So-Sew Styles, Inc.',
        20 => 'Flint Sportswear',
        21 => 'New England Industries Inc.',
        22 => 'Provisor Sportswear',
        23 => 'Ringer Co.',
        24 => 'Atomic Sportswear',
        25 => 'Milford Mfg. Co.',
        26 => 'Lustberg, Nast & Co. Inc.',
        27 => 'Leco Industries Inc.',
        28 => 'неизвестный',
        29 => 'Dan Jac Sportswear',
        30 => 'Vista Corp.',
        31 => 'Sunset Sportswear Inc.'
        ),
    68 => array(
        1 => 'Defense Personnel Support Center',
        2 => 'Apparel Corp. Of America',
        3 => 'John Ownbey Company, Inc.',
        4 => 'So-Sew Styles, Inc.',
        5 => 'Rolane Sportswear, Inc.',
        6 => 'Bonham Manufacturing Co., Inc.',
        7 => 'Alpha Industries, Inc.',
        8 => 'Sportsmaster Inc.',
        9 => 'Mason & Hughes Inc.',
        10 => 'Appleman Mfg. Co.',
        11 => 'Allen Overall Co., Inc.'
        ),
    69 => array(
        1 => 'Rolane Sportswear, Inc.',
        2 => 'Apparel Corp. Of America',
        3 => 'Alpha Industries, Inc.',
        4 => 'So-Sew Styles, Inc.',
        5 => 'Sportsmaster Inc.',
        6 => 'Allen Overall Co., Inc.',
        7 => 'John Ownbey Company, Inc.'
        ),
    70 => array(
        1 => 'John Ownbey Company, Inc.',
        2 => 'Alpha Industries, Inc.',
        3 => 'Rolane Sportswear, Inc.',
        4 => 'So-Sew Styles, Inc.',
        5 => 'Allen Overall Co., Inc.',
        6 => 'Southern Athletic, Inc.'
        ),
    71 => array(
        1 => 'Alpha Industries, Inc.',
        2 => 'John Ownbey Company, Inc.',
        3 => 'So-Sew Styles, Inc.',
        4 => 'Rolane Sportswear, Inc.'
        ),
    72 => array(
        1 => 'John Ownbey Company, Inc.',
        2 => 'So-Sew Styles, Inc.',
        3 => 'Alpha Industries, Inc.',
        4 => 'Rolane Sportswear, Inc.'
        ),
    73 => array(
        1 => 'So-Sew Styles, Inc.',
        2 => 'Alpha Industries, Inc.',
        3 => 'John Ownbey Company, Inc.'
        ),
    74 => array(
        1 => 'Defense Personnel Support Center',
        2 => 'So-Sew Styles, Inc.',
        3 => 'Alpha Industries, Inc.',
        4 => 'John Ownbey Company, Inc.'
        ),
    75 => array(
        1 => 'So-Sew Styles, Inc.',
        2 => 'Alpha Industries, Inc.',
        3 => 'Cherokee Industries, Inc.'
        ),
    76 => array(
        1 => 'Defense Personnel Support Center',
        2 => 'Winfield Manufacturing Co., Inc.',
        3 => 'Alpha Industries, Inc.',
        4 => 'So-Sew Styles, Inc.',
        5 => 'John Ownbey Company, Inc.'
        ),
    77 => array(
        1 => 'Defense Personnel Support Center',
        2 => 'Alpha Industries, Inc.',
        3 => 'So-Sew Styles, Inc.',
        4 => 'John Ownbey Company, Inc.'
        ),
    78 => array(
        1 => 'So-Sew Styles, Inc.',
        2 => 'Alpha Industries, Inc.',
        3 => 'John Ownbey Company, Inc.',
        4 => 'Issachar Manufacturing Co., Inc.'
        ),
    79 => array(
        1 => 'Defense Personnel Support Center',
        2 => 'So-Sew Styles, Inc.',
        3 => 'Alpha Industries, Inc.'
        ),
    80 => array(
        1 => 'Issachar Manufacturing Co., Inc.',
        2 => 'John Ownbey Company, Inc.',
        3 => 'Alpha Industries, Inc.',
        4 => 'So-Sew Styles, Inc.',
        5 => 'Golden Mfg. Co., Inc.'
        ),
    81 => array(
        1 => 'Defense Personnel Support Center',
        2 => 'So-Sew Styles, Inc.',
        3 => 'Alpha Industries, Inc.',
        4 => 'Golden Mfg. Co., Inc.',
        5 => 'John Ownbey Company, Inc.',
        6 => 'Dakota Industries, Inc.',
        7 => 'Winfield Manufacturing Co., Inc.'
        ),
    82 => array(
        1 => 'Defense Personnel Support Center',
        2 => 'Golden Mfg. Co., Inc.',
        3 => 'Alpha Industries, Inc.',
        4 => 'So-Sew Styles, Inc.',
        5 => 'Vanderbilt Shirt Co., Inc.'
        ),
    83 => array(
        1 => 'Defense Personnel Support Center',
        2 => 'John Ownbey Company, Inc.'
        ),
    84 => array(
        1 => 'Defense Personnel Support Center',
        2 => 'Golden Mfg. Co., Inc.'
        ),
    85 => array(
        1 => 'Golden Mfg. Co., Inc.'
        ),
    86 => array(
        1 => 'So-Sew Styles, Inc.'
        ),
    87 => array(
        1 => 'So-Sew Styles, Inc.'
        ),
    89 => array(
        1 => 'So-Sew Styles, Inc.'
        ),
    91 => array(
        1 => 'American Apparel, Inc.'
        ),
    );

$kinds = array(
    63 => array(
        1 => array(
            T635 => 'Т-63-5'
            ),
        ),
    64 => array(
        1 => array(
            T635 => 'Т-63-5'
            ),
        ),
    65 => array(
        1 => array(
            DSA18666 => 'DSA-1-8666'
            ),
        ),
    66 => array(
        1 => array(
            DSA100817 => 'DSA 100-817',
            DSA1001690 => 'DSA 100-1690',
            DSA1003378 => 'DSA 100-3378'
            ),
        2 => array(
            DSA1001691 => 'DSA 100-1691'
            ),
        3 => array(
            DSA1001928 => 'DSA 100-1928',
            DSA1002365 => 'DSA 100-2365'
            ),
        4 => array(
            DSA1002366 => 'DSA 100-2366',
            DSA1003255 => 'DSA 100-3255'
            ),
        5 => array(
            DSA1002936 => 'DSA 100-2936'
            ),
        6 => array(
            DSA1003491 => 'DSA 100-3491'
            ),
        7 => array(
            DSA1004542 => 'DSA 100-4542'
            ),
        8 => array(
            DSA1004544 => 'DSA 100-4544'
            ),
        9 => array(
            DSA1004899 => 'DSA 100-4899'
            ),
        10 => array(
            DSA1005005 => 'DSA 100-5005'
            ),
        ),
    67 => array(
        1 => array(
            DSA10067C0107 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0107'
            ),
        2 => array(
            DSA10067C0115 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0115'
            ),
        3 => array(
            DSA10067C0116 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0116'
            ),
        4 => array(
            DSA10067C0117 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0117'
            ),
        5 => array(
            DSA10067C0125 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0125'
            ),
        6 => array(
            DSA10067C0126 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0126'
            ),
        7 => array(
            DSA10067C0159 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0159'
            ),
        8 => array(
            DSA10067C0165 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0165'
            ),
        9 => array(
            DSA10067C0183 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0183',
            DSA10067C0759 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0759'
            ),
        10 => array(
            DSA10067C0186 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0186'
            ),
        11 => array(
            DSA10067C0195 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0195'
            ),
        12 => array(
            DSA10067C0213 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0213'
            ),
        13 => array(
            DSA10067C0217 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0217'
            ),
        14 => array(
            DSA10067C0221 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0221'
            ),
        15 => array(
            DSA10067C0249 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0249',
            DSA10067C0706 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0706'
            ),
        16 => array(
            DSA10067C3536 => 'DSA 100-67-C-3536'
            ),
        17 => array(
            DSA10067C3537 => 'DSA 100-67-C-3537',
            DSA10067C4097 => 'DSA 100-67-C-4097',
            DSA10067C4426 => 'DSA 100-67-C-4426'
            ),
        18 => array(
            DSA10067C4425 => 'DSA 100-67-C-4425'
            ),
        19 => array(
            DSA10067C4540 => 'DSA 100-67-C-4540'
            ),
        20 => array(
            DSA10067C0640 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0640'
            ),
        21 => array(
            DSA10067C0641 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0641'
            ),
        22 => array(
            DSA10067C0648 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0648'
            ),
        23 => array(
            DSA10067C0653 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0653'
            ),
        24 => array(
            DSA10067C0655 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0655'
            ),
        25 => array(
            DSA10067C0669 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0669'
            ),
        26 => array(
            DSA10067C0683 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0683'
            ),
        27 => array(
            DSA10067C0692 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0692'
            ),
        28 => array(
            DSA10067C0746 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0746'
            ),
        29 => array(
            DSA10067C0747 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0747'
            ),
        30 => array(
            DSA10067C0767 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0767'
            ),
        31 => array(
            DSA10067C0778 => 'DSA 100-67-C-0778'
            ),
        ),
    68 => array(
        1 => array(
            8025 => '8025*',
            8118 => '8118*'
            ),
        2 => array(
            DSA10068C0411 => 'DSA 100-68-C-0411',
            DSA10068C2016 => 'DSA 100-68-C-2016'
            ),
        3 => array(
            DSA10068C0471 => 'DSA 100-68-C-0471'
            ),
        4 => array(
            DSA10068C0472 => 'DSA 100-68-C-0472',
            DSA10068C2019 => 'DSA 100-68-C-2019'
            ),
        5 => array(
            DSA10068C0967 => 'DSA 100-68-C-0967'
            ),
        6 => array(
            DSA10068C0968 => 'DSA 100-68-C-0968'
            ),
        7 => array(
            DSA10068C1044 => 'DSA 100-68-C-1044',
            DSA10068C1974 => 'DSA 100-68-C-1974'
            ),
        8 => array(
            DSA10068C2017 => 'DSA 100-68-C-2017',
            DSA10068C2171 => 'DSA 100-68-C-2171'
            ),
        9 => array(
            DSA10068C2018 => 'DSA 100-68-C-2018'
            ),
        10 => array(
            DSA10068C2372 => 'DSA 100-68-C-2372'
            ),
        11 => array(
            DSA10068C2373 => 'DSA 100-68-C-2373'
            ),
        ),
    69 => array(
        1 => array(
            DSA10069C0760 => 'DSA 100-69-C-0760',
            DSA10069C2482 => 'DSA 100-69-C-2482'
            ),
        2 => array(
            DSA10069C0761 => 'DSA 100-69-C-0761'
            ),
        3 => array(
            DSA10069C0762 => 'DSA 100-69-C-0762',
            DSA10069C2317 => 'DSA 100-69-C-2317'
            ),
        4 => array(
            DSA10069C0818 => 'DSA 100-69-C-0818',
            DSA10069C2483 => 'DSA 100-69-C-2483'
            ),
        5 => array(
            DSA10069C1006 => 'DSA 100-69-C-1006',
            DSA10069C2484 => 'DSA 100-69-C-2484'
            ),
        6 => array(
            DSA10069C1086 => 'DSA 100-69-C-1086'
            ),
        7 => array(
            DSA10069C1087 => 'DSA 100-69-C-1087'
            ),
        ),
    70 => array(
        1 => array(
            DSA10070C0525 => 'DSA 100-70-C-0525',
            DSA10070C0613 => 'DSA 100-70-C-0613'
            ),
        2 => array(
            DSA10070C0606 => 'DSA 100-70-C-0606'
            ),
        3 => array(
            DSA10070C0607 => 'DSA 100-70-C-0607'
            ),
        4 => array(
            DSA10070C0644 => 'DSA 100-70-C-0644'
            ),
        5 => array(
            DSA10070C0645 => 'DSA 100-70-C-0645'
            ),
        6 => array(
            DSA10070C0646 => 'DSA 100-70-C-0646'
            ),
        ),
    71 => array(
        1 => array(
            DSA10071C0180 => 'DSA 100-71-C-0180',
            DSA10071C1337 => 'DSA 100-71-C-1337'
            ),
        2 => array(
            DSA10071C0181 => 'DSA 100-71-C-0181'
            ),
        3 => array(
            DSA10071C0201 => 'DSA 100-71-C-0201'
            ),
        4 => array(
            DSA10071C0246 => 'DSA 100-71-C-0246'
            ),
        ),
    72 => array(
        1 => array(
            DSA10072C0130 => 'DSA 100-72-C-0130',
            DSA10072C0702 => 'DSA 100-72-C-0702',
            DSA10072C1203 => 'DSA 100-72-C-1203',
            DSA10072C1733 => 'DSA 100-72-C-1733'
            ),
        2 => array(
            DSA10072C0131 => 'DSA 100-72-C-0131',
            DSA10072C1091 => 'DSA 100-72-C-1091',
            DSA10072C1732 => 'DSA 100-72-C-1732'
            ),
        3 => array(
            DSA10072C0132 => 'DSA 100-72-C-0132',
            DSA10072C0703 => 'DSA 100-72-C-0703',
            DSA10072C1202 => 'DSA 100-72-C-1202',
            DSA10072C1666 => 'DSA 100-72-C-1666'
            ),
        4 => array(
            DSA10072C0779 => 'DSA 100-72-C-0779'
            ),
        ),
    73 => array(
        1 => array(
            DSA10073C0358 => 'DSA 100-73-C-0358',
            DSA10073C1019 => 'DSA 100-73-C-1019'
            ),
        2 => array(
            DSA10073C0856 => 'DSA 100-73-C-0856'
            ),
        3 => array(
            DSA10073C1022 => 'DSA 100-73-C-1022'
            ),
        ),
    74 => array(
        1 => array(
            801674 => '8016-74'
            ),
        2 => array(
            DSA10074C0129 => 'DSA 100-74-C-0129',
            DSA10074C1416 => 'DSA 100-74-C-1416'
            ),
        3 => array(
            DSA10074C0130 => 'DSA 100-74-C-0130',
            DSA10074C1417 => 'DSA 100-74-C-1417'
            ),
        4 => array(
            DSA10074C0354 => 'DSA 100-74-C-0354',
            DSA10074C1415 => 'DSA 100-74-C-1415'
            ),
        ),
    75 => array(
        1 => array(
            DSA10075C0510 => 'DSA 100-75-C-0510'
            ),
        2 => array(
            DSA10075C0511 => 'DSA 100-75-C-0511',
            DSA10075C1376 => 'DSA 100-75-C-1376'
            ),
        3 => array(
            DSA10075C1200 => 'DSA 100-75-C-1200'
            ),
        ),
    76 => array(
        1 => array(
            605376 => '6053-76',
            902376 => '9023-76'
            ),
        2 => array(
            DSA10076C0605 => 'DSA 100-76-C-0605'
            ),
        3 => array(
            DSA10076C0739 => 'DSA 100-76-C-0739',
            DSA10076C1003 => 'DSA 100-76-C-1003'
            ),
        4 => array(
            DSA10076C0889 => 'DSA 100-76-C-0889',
            DSA10076C1084 => 'DSA 100-76-C-1084'
            ),
        5 => array(
            DSA10076C1083 => 'DSA 100-76-C-1083'
            ),
        ),
    77 => array(
        1 => array(
            711677 => '7116-77',
            715077 => '7150-77',
            727077 => '7270-77'
            ),
        2 => array(
            DSA10077C0684 => 'DSA 100-77-C-0684',
            DSA10077C1387 => 'DSA 100-77-C-1387'
            ),
        3 => array(
            DSA10077C0796 => 'DSA 100-77-C-0796',
            DSA10077C1386 => 'DSA 100-77-C-1386'
            ),
        4 => array(
            DSA10077C1385 => 'DSA 100-77-C-1385'
            ),
        ),
    78 => array(
        1 => array(
            DLA10078C0378 => 'DLA 100-78-C-0378',
            DLA10078C1219 => 'DLA 100-78-C-1219'
            ),
        2 => array(
            DLA10078C0379 => 'DLA 100-78-C-0379',
            DLA10078C1098 => 'DLA 100-78-C-1098'
            ),
        3 => array(
            DLA10078C0528 => 'DLA 100-78-C-0528',
            DLA10078C1097 => 'DLA 100-78-C-1097'
            ),
        4 => array(
            DLA10078C1205 => 'DLA 100-78-C-1205'
            ),
        ),
    79 => array(
        1 => array(
            913679 => '9136-79'
            ),
        2 => array(
            DLA10079C2904 => 'DLA 100-79-C-2904'
            ),
        3 => array(
            DLA10079C2905 => 'DLA 100-79-C-2905'
            ),
        ),
    80 => array(
        1 => array(
            DLA10080C2462 => 'DLA 100-80-C-2462'
            ),
        2 => array(
            DLA10080C2529 => 'DLA 100-80-C-2529',
            DLA10080C3301 => 'DLA 100-80-C-3301'
            ),
        3 => array(
            DLA10080C2530 => 'DLA 100-80-C-2530',
            DLA10080C3302 => 'DLA 100-80-C-3302'
            ),
        4 => array(
            DLA10080C2676 => 'DLA 100-80-C-2676'
            ),
        5 => array(
            DLA10080C3303 => 'DLA 100-80-C-3303'
            ),
        ),
    81 => array(
        1 => array(
            711081 => '7110-81'
            ),
        2 => array(
            DLA10081C2335 => 'DLA 100-81-C-2335',
            DLA10081C3070 => 'DLA 100-81-C-3070'
            ),
        3 => array(
            DLA10081C2336 => 'DLA 100-81-C-2336',
            DLA10081C3071 => 'DLA 100-81-C-3071',
            DLA10081C3463 => 'DLA 100-81-C-3463'
            ),
        4 => array(
            DLA10081C2337 => 'DLA 100-81-C-2337'
            ),
        5 => array(
            DLA10081C2485 => 'DLA 100-81-C-2485',
            DLA10081C3464 => 'DLA 100-81-C-3464'
            ),
        6 => array(
            DLA10081C2501 => 'DLA 100-81-C-2501'
            ),
        7 => array(
            DLA10081C3462 => 'DLA 100-81-C-3462'
            ),
        ),
    82 => array(
        1 => array(
            804882 => '8048-82'
            ),
        2 => array(
            DLA10082C0574 => 'DLA 100-82-C-0574'
            ),
        3 => array(
            DLA10082C0575 => 'DLA 100-82-C-0575'
            ),
        4 => array(
            DLA10082C0576 => 'DLA 100-82-C-0576'
            ),
        5 => array(
            DLA10082C0577 => 'DLA 100-82-C-0577'
            ),
        ),
    83 => array(
        1 => array(
            903183 => '9031-83'
            ),
        2 => array(
            DLA10083C0655 => 'DLA 100-83-C-0655'
            ),
        ),
    84 => array(
        1 => array(
            617484 => '6174-84',
            913184 => '9131-84'
            ),
        2 => array(
            DLA10084C0292 => 'DLA 100-84-C-0292'
            ),
        ),
    85 => array(
        1 => array(
            DLA10085C0379 => 'DLA 100-85-C-0379'
            ),
        ),
    86 => array(
        1 => array(
            DLA10086C0442 => 'DLA 100-86-C-0442'
            ),
        ),
    87 => array(
        1 => array(
            DLA10087C0591 => 'DLA 100-87-C-0591'
            ),
        ),
    89 => array(
        1 => array(
            DLA10089C0360 => 'DLA 100-89-C-0360'
            ),
        ),
    91 => array(
        1 => array(
            DLA10091C0450 => 'DLA 100-91-C-0450'
            )
        )
    );

    // Проверяем наличие переменной, которая укажет данному сценарию какие именно данные нужны
if (!isset($_POST['query']) || !$_POST['query']) {
    exit("Нет данных определяющих тип запроса");
}
else {
    // Сохраняем строку запроса данных в отдельной переменной
    $query = trim($_POST['query']); // Очищаем от лишних пробелов

    // Определяем тип запроса
    switch($query) {
    case 'getKinds':    // Запрос на получение видов транспорта
        // Сохраним в переменную значение выбранного типа транспорта
        $type_id = trim($_POST['type_id']); // Очистим его от лишних пробелов
        // Формируем массив с ответом
        $result = NULL;
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($types[$type_id] as $kind_id => $kind) {
            $result[$i]['kind_id'] = $kind_id;
            $result[$i]['kind'] = $kind;
            $i++;
        }
        break;
    case 'getCategories':   // Запрос на получение видов транспорта
        // Сохраним в переменные значения выбранных типа транспорта и вида транспорта
        $type_id = trim($_POST['type_id']); // Очистим их от лишних пробелов
        $kind_id = trim($_POST['kind_id']);
        // Формируем массив с ответом
        $result = NULL;
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($kinds[$type_id][$kind_id] as $category_id => $category) {
            $result[$i]['category_id'] = $category_id;
            $result[$i]['category'] = $category;
            $i++;
        }
        break;
        default:
        // Если данные не определены
        $result = NULL;
        break;
    }
}

// Преобразуем данные в формат json, чтобы их смог обработать JavaScript-сценарий, приславший запрос
echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

I want to navigating the page displays all of the elements of the list, and when you select something show only the relevant elements. Please help solve this problem.

Comment: Well where is the HTML sending its selected option ? you have '!isset($_POST['query'])' but i dont see 'query' it in your html. or 'category_id'..

Comment: Have you actually tried to do this yourself?  You might also benefit from some storage volume like a database or XML/JSON files rather than storing it all in a PHP script.

Comment: Why would angular be the 'perfect solution' ? Anyway OP Please post your JS code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Javascript - as you have not posted the JS code..

You need to send the details from your HTML to the PHP page..

For example your select tag has no 'name' to identify it to the PHP POST page..

so you need something like :

```
       <select id="type" name="type_id" multiple> ....
```

The name then informs the php that you are sending the value to the $_POST['type_id'];

Fixing your HTML to be in line with the PHP expectations should solve your problem..

Edit : (More Info)
The HTML needs to send the information and Values you want to the PHP code so the PHP can work with it. If looks like you are using .ajax to send the data to the PHP but your HTML is not named..

Your php $_POST['NAME_OF_INPUT'];

Comes from HTML 'name' tag.. an example :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['testName']))
echo "You entered : ".$_POST['testName'];
```

?>

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input name="testName" type="text"/>
<button>Submit</button>
```

// your code goes here

https://ideone.com/nxJ8G5

Comment: added more info. I suggest you start from the basics of HTML and php forms. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp